# Вставить в TextView EditText

Tags: android

Есть предложение представляющее собой форму в которую пользователю необходимо вписать своё имя. Я столкнулся с проблемой переноса строки при её реализации.

Я сделал следующее: Для каждого предложения, в которое пользователь должен ввести данные я создал `LinearLayout`, в этот `LinearLayout` я поместил `TextView`(начало предложения), затем `EditText`(данные, которые необходимо вставить пользователю) и снова `TextView`(окончание предложения).

Но перенос строк работает таким образом, что переносит строку(не уместившееся предложение) под второй `TextView`, а мне необходимо,чтобы он переносил ее на новую строку под первый `TextView`, чтобы сделать читабельный текст. Как это правильно реализовать?

Выглядит сейчас:

```
|блабла_________блаблабла|
                блабла
```

Должно выглядить:

```
|блабла_________блаблабла|
 блабла
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/firstPart_1"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:ems="7"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/firstPart_2"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Попробовал использовать [FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView), но даннный виджет не могу вставить в `ListView` для того, чтобы выровнить по уровню с `EditText`, все просто пропадает. А если не вставляю (код ниже), то он просто появляется в самом верху и обтекает мой `ListView` с элементами (как на картинке ниже).

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private FlowTextView flowTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    flowTextView = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.ftv);
    String content = getString(R.string.lorem);
    Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(content);
    flowTextView.setText(html);

}}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView
        android:id="@+id/ftv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="блабла"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:ems="5"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По всей видимости стандартными средствами такое реализовать невозможно, так как требуется перенести часть виджета на другую сторону. нужно делать кастомный виджет или искать что то готовое на GitHub (мне вспомнилось только из области [flow-text](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView) - может можно как то присобить)

Comment: @pavlofff я добавил в описании выше попытку реализации через `flow-text`, не могу понять, как вставить виджет в `LinearLayout` для того, чтобы выровнить текст по `EditText`

Comment: Стандартными элементами такое не сделать. Это только если свой компонент писать, где будет динамически пересчитываться длина строки, затем будет создаваться новый TextView на след. строке с остатками текста.

Comment: @Suvitruf Жду вашего комментария) [по данному посту](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482808/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)