# Как улучшить качество Распознавания голоса?

Tags: android, распознавание-речи

Работаю над приложением позволяющим распознавать голос, и переводить его в текст, то есть `Speech to Text`. Затем приложение сравнивает фразу и если она совпадает с фразой из условия, то программа выполняет определенную функцию. Проблема в том, что качество распознавания оставляет желать лучшего, возможно ли его как-то улучшить? Возможно мой метод устарел и сейчас используют более продвинутые методы?(брал из книги 2013года) Или применить другую технологию с учетом того, что пользователь использует определенный набор фраз (их около 20)?

Мой метод используемый для распознавания:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Comment: Программно улучшить нельзя. Все зависит от микрофона. Разве что говорить в упор..